# Powershell AD Script - Add a number onto the end of account Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Another question regarding this dreaded script. I have ran into a brick wall. 
The way usernames at my organisation are created, are SurnameInitial. However, if the account already exists we put a number on the end. If that number exists, it changes to the next number  (TestT , TestT1 , TestT2 ... etc )

I can't figure out how to get the script to do this, it simply does not create the account if it already exists in the AD

The following is relevant code to help you understand how it currently manages account creation.

```
#region Unique Field Data

# Acquiring unique field data
$GivenName = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The New User's First Name?"
Write-Host " "

$Surname = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The New User's Last Name?"
Write-Host " "

$Description = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The Job Title & Department Of The New User? [Please format as Job Title – Dept]"
Write-Host " "

#endregion

#region Data Generation

$DisplayName = $GivenName + " " + $Surname

$Mail = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + "RE"

$MailAlias = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + $DNSRoot2

$SInitial = $Surname[0]
$Initial = $GivenName[0]
$SAMAccountName = $Surname+$Initial
$SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
$UserPrincipalName = $Surname+$Initial
$HD = "U"
$HDir = "\\RBHFILRED002\"
$AC = "Users_01$\"
$DH = "Users_02$\"
$IM = "Users_03$\"
$NS = "Users_04$\"
$TZ = "Users_05$\"
$Folder = if ($SInitial -in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'd','e','f', 'g','h'){$DH}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'i','j','k', 'l','m'){$IM}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'n','o','p', 'q','r','s'){$NS}
      Else {$TZ}

$group1 = "zz Everyone"
$group2 = "Safeboot Domain Users"
cls

#endregion

#region User Creation

# Create The User

Get-ChildItem
New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk" -SamAccountName $Surname$Initial -Name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName -GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Surname -EmailAddress $Mail -UserPrincipalName $Surname$Initial@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk -Title $title -HomeDrive $HD -HomeDirectory $HDir$Folder$Surname$Initial -Description $Description -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -AccountPassword $defpassword -Enabled $true -PassThru
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls

#endregion
```

Hopefully my code is clear, and can be understood & hopefully you guys are able to offer support.

Pre-Emptive Thank You

**EDIT BELOW**

So I've expanded on the script, using a suggestion below.

```
#region User Creation

# Create The User


$i = 1
$AccountCreated = $False
Do {
Try {
New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk" -SamAccountName $Surname$Initial -Name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName -GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Surname -EmailAddress $Mail -UserPrincipalName $Surname$Initial@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk -Title $title -HomeDrive $HD -HomeDirectory $HDir$Folder$Surname$Initial -Description $Description -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -AccountPassword $defpassword -Enabled $true -PassThru 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 -Members $SAMAccountName
Set $AccountCreated to $True
}
Catch {
New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk" -SamAccountName $Surname$Initial$I -Name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName -GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Surname -UserPrincipalName $Surname$Initial$I@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk -Title $title -HomeDrive $HD -HomeDirectory $HDir$Folder$Surname$Initial -Description $Description -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -AccountPassword $defpassword -Enabled $true -PassThru 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 -Members $SAMAccountName
Increment $I
}
}
Until ($AccountCreated -eq $True)

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls

#endregion

#region Post-Creation

echo "Username:" $SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "
echo "Password:" "Welcome123"
Write-Host " "
echo "Email:" $Mail
Write-Host " "
echo "Job Title - Department:" $Description
Write-Host " "
echo "Home Directory:" $HDir$Folder$Surname$Initial
Write-Host " "

#endregion
```

However, this creates the account. But doesn't update the exchange creation with the incremented username (so doesn't create a mailbox), does not create the correct home directory, and does not echo the correct details based on if it's incremented.

I cannot figure out how to now do this

**EDIT TWO**

Following further help from James C, I have created the following code. However, it does not create a Mail account. And Now Throws out an error.

```
$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$i = 1
cls

#endregion

#region User Creation

# Create The User


While ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName) -ne $null){
$SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i
$i++
}

$NewUserParams = @{
path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
Name                  = $DisplayName
DisplayName           = $DisplayName
GivenName             = $GivenName
Surname               = $Surname
EmailAddress          = $Mail
UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk"
Title                 = $title
HomeDrive             = $HomeDrive
HomeDirectory         = "$HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName"
Description           = $Description
ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
AccountPassword       = $defpassword
Enabled               = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls

#endregion

#region Post-Creation

echo "Username:" $SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "
echo "Password:" "Welcome123"
Write-Host " "
echo "Email:" $Mail
Write-Host " "
echo "Job Title - Department:" $Description
Write-Host " "
echo "Home Directory:" $HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "

#endregion
```

It produces the following Error

```
Name        : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
PSVersion   : 1.0
Description : Admin Tasks for the Exchange Server

Name        : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Support
PSVersion   : 1.0
Description : Support Tasks for the Exchange Server

This tool is to be used for creating User Accounts for the RBFT Domain under Ultima Business Solutions only. If this     applies, please hit any key to continue.

Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:139 char:9
+ While ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName) -ne $null){
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADUser) [Get-ADUser],     ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm  ands.GetADUser

New-ADUser : An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:163 char:1
+ New-ADUser @NewUserParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Timms James,...tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk 
   :String) [New-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : An attempt was made to add an object to the dire ctory with a name that is already in use,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Managem  ent.Commands.NewADUser

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:164 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGro upMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Micros oft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:165 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGro upMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox..
Enable-Mailbox : The operation couldn't be performed because object 'TimmsJ1' couldn't be found on 'ad1.rbbh-tr.nhs.uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:171 char:1
+ Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Enable-Mailbox], Manage mentObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2B788636,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Recipient Tasks.EnableMailbox

Username:
TimmsJ1

Password:
Welcome123

Email:
James.Timms@royalberkshire.nhs.uk

Job Title - Department:
Ultima - Ultima

Home Directory:
\\RBHFILRED002\Users_05$\TimmsJ1

You will need to manually set the new user's group memberships. Please Do 
This Before Sending The User's Account Details.


Press Any Key To Close
```

It creates the User account and Email if $SAMAccount is duplicate, however if the GivenName and Surname are duplicates it will not create the account at all.

It's for the National Health Trust in the UK, so obviously a lot of employees, especially ones with common names will have duplicate names.

Any fix for this?

**Edit Three**

Kind of fixed the issue above, by creating a new string.
However, it still remains that that account will refuse to create if the First + Second name are duplicates of another.

This is an issue as stated previously, due to the fact there are many people within the NHS that have the same name.

```
#region Data Generation

$DisplayName = $Surname + " " + $GivenName

$Mail = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"

$MailAlias = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + $DNSRoot2

$SInitial = $Surname[0]
$Initial = $GivenName[0]
$SAMAccountName = $Surname + "" + $Initial
$SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
$UserPrincipalName = $Surname+$Initial
$HD = "U"
$HDir = "\\RBHFILRED002\"
$AC = "Users_01$\"
$DH = "Users_02$\"
$IM = "Users_03$\"
$NS = "Users_04$\"
$TZ = "Users_05$\"

$Folder = if ($SInitial -in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'd','e','f', 'g','h'){$DH}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'i','j','k', 'l','m'){$IM}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'n','o','p', 'q','r','s'){$NS}
      Else {$TZ}

$group1 = "zz Everyone"
$group2 = "Safeboot Domain Users"

$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$email = $GivenName + "." + $Surname
$i = 1
cls

#endregion

#region User Creation

# Create The User

While ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null){
$SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i
$Mail = $email + [string]$i + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"
$i++

}

$NewUserParams = @{
path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
Name                  = $DisplayName
DisplayName           = $DisplayName
GivenName             = $GivenName
Surname               = $Surname
EmailAddress          = $Mail
UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk"
Title                 = $title
HomeDrive             = $HomeDrive
HomeDirectory         = "$HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName"
Description           = $Description
ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
AccountPassword       = $defpassword
Enabled               = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Start-Sleep -s 10
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls

#endregion
```

Once again, any Ideas?

Comment: You need to do this: Ask for the user input -> check for an existing matching user (`Get-ADUSer`) -> update the user input (add number suffix, if needed) -> create new user.  I don't see you doing steps 2 or 3.

Comment: How do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Using a [Do/While](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/05/powershell-looping-understanding-and-using-do-while/) loop with `Get-ADUser` to search for a free username and `$VariableName++` to increment the number for the username each loop.

Also updated your `New-ADUser` command to use [splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) as this makes it much easier to read.

```
#didn't include rest of your code above here as it hasn't changed

$group1 = "zz Everyone"
$group2 = "Safeboot Domain Users"

$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$i = 1

While ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null){
    $SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i
    $i++
}

$NewUserParams = @{
    path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
    SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
    Name                  = $DisplayName
    DisplayName           = $DisplayName
    GivenName             = $GivenName
    Surname               = $Surname
    EmailAddress          = "$GivenName.$Surname$i@royalberkshire.nhs.uk"
    UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk"
    Title                 = $title
    HomeDrive             = $HomeDrive
    HomeDirectory         = "$HDir$Folder$Surname$Initial"
    Description           = $Description
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
    PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
    AccountPassword       = $defpassword
    Enabled               = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName

Write-Output "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30
Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
```

Comment: I'll give you a test. Thank you for this.

Only thing that doesn't seem to be done, is the email with the number.

How would I go about doing this because The email would need to be givenname.surname(number if needed)@royalberkshire.nhs.uk

Comment: Also, It seems to be throwing an Error whenever the account exists. It doesn't increment at all

Comment: You able to help?

Comment: Updated code to a single `while` statement as this is cleaner

Comment: Produces an Error

Comment: Rather than repeatedly querying AD, I would probably query once for `$ExistingUsers = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$defaultname*)").SamAccountName`, and then while looping to find a unique account check `$SamAccountName -in $ExistingUsers`.

Comment: Added `SilentlyContinue` to `Get-ADUser` so it returns null instead of an error. Also updated EmailAddress attribute too. You may also need a `Start-Sleep` before the first `Add-ADGroupMember`if you AD replication isn't fast.

Comment: I Added an Edit 3 @BaconBits Any Idea?

Comment: James C, there's further edits, are you able to assist further?

Answer (score -1):

you could put your account creation in a do until loop with a try catch inside i.e. something like this semi sudo code

```
$i = 1
$AccountCreated = $False
Do {
$i = 1
$AccountCreated = $False
$AccountName = $Surname$Initial
Do {
Try {
New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk" -SamAccountName 
$AccountName = $Surname$Initial -Name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName 
-GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Surname -EmailAddress $Mail - 
UserPrincipalName $AccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk -Title $title -HomeDrive $HD - 
HomeDirectory $HDir$Folder$AccountName -Description $Description - 
ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -AccountPassword 
$defpassword -Enabled $true -PassThru 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 -Members $SAMAccountName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 -Members $SAMAccountName
Set $AccountCreated to $True
}
Catch {
$AccountName = $Surname$Initial + $i
Increment $I
}
}
}
Until ($AccountCreated -eq $True)
```

Comment: It would need to scale the number up.
We can SOmetimes have 10 people with the same username since it's a national health service.
SamS / SamS1 / SamS2 / SamS3

Comment: that should in the catch block, the first time it fails to create the account 1 will get applied to the end of the account name and $I gets incremented.  Then it will try and create the account again and if it fails it will drop into the catch block again and append 2 to the end etc.

Comment: So I add the 2 to the end of the script or nah?

Comment: I've figured out what you mean, however I now have an issue.

The script also creates an exchange mailbox for the user, using
`Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName`
However, this obviously flags that the exchange account already exists for the user.
How do i make it take the $i into account if it had to use the $i.

Also at the end, i echo the username, and obviously it's the wrong username if it has to use $i
@simon

Comment: ok, you could put the exchange account creation into a function that gets called after the account creation in the try block.  This would only get called after a successful account creation.  That way you would know the username needed for the exchange account

Comment: Although this does show the way the problem should be approached, it's not a good answer as you mix actual Powershell commands with sudo code. This approach is likely to be confusing to someone who doesn't have a good grasp on the actual language as they won't know what is and isn't an actual usable command.

Comment: So what should I do regarding this?

I've edited the OP to show what I mean by this, and the code that needs editing

Answer (score -1):

ok just to give you the idea try something like this

```
$Myusername = "test"
$Mastername = $Myusername
For ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
Write-Host $Myusername
$myusername = $Mastername + $i
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, all it does is output a list of the username with numbers added to them. There's no indication of how to test the username candidates and select the first option that is available to use.

Comment: @JamesC. are you able to assist?