# Trying to create a powershell user creation script, want to append number to username if it already exists

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a user creation script as a way to teach myself more Powershell. Currently I am only working on creating just the username and want to make sure each username is unique.

After a user inputs the name and number of a user the script should do the following.

Get the the first name
Get the middle initial
Get the last name
Combine the first letter of the first name + middle initial + 6 characters from the last name
If users already exists, add number starting at 1 until username is unique.
I am currently stuck on step 5. If the username is not unique it appends a number one. I.E. User Brenda T Follower has a username of BTFollow and if that username exists already it becomes BTFollow1.

However if BTFollow and BTFollow1 already exist instead of making BTFollow2 it makes BTFollow12.

Lastly, although not a huge issue I want my parameters to show what comes after Read-Host but that text is not appearing only the variable name.

Here is my code.

```
Param(
#Gather users first name, required input and must not be empty or null
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]
$FirstName = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please input the users first name.'),

#Gather users middle initial, required input and must not be empty or null and must only be one character
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[ValidateLength(1,1)]
[string]
$MiddleInitial = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please input the users middle initial.'),

#Gather users last name, required input and must not be empty or null
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]
$LastName = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please input the users last name.'),

#Gathers user phone extension, required input, mustn ot be empty or null, and must only user numbers
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[ValidatePattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")]
[ValidateLength(4,4)]
[String]
$PhoneExtension = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please input the users 4 digit exension, numbers only')
)

$i = 0



#Create user name
$Username = $FirstName.Substring(0,1) + $MiddleInitial + $LastName.Substring(0,6)

#Check username does not exist, if it does add numbers

Do {
    Try {
        Get-ADUser $UserName | Out-Null
        $UserName = $Username + ++$i
        Continue
    }
    Catch {
        Break
    }
} While ($True)

Write-Host "Username is $Username"
```

Comment: take a look at the 1st answer here ... active directory - Powershell AD Script - Add a number onto the end of account Name - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694247/powershell-ad-script-add-a-number-onto-the-end-of-account-name

Comment: That did not work at all.

Comment: As for "I want my parameters to show what comes after Read-Host but that text is not appearing only the variable name": It's an interesting problem, but please ask in it in a new, separate question.

Comment: @AustinDowning - this line `$SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i` sure seems to work. i guess we must be thinking of different things. however, your answer below sure looks similar ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

Because you *iteratively modified* `$UserName` in your loop, you ended up appending an *additional* number in each iteration:

> ```
> $UserName = $Username + ++$i
> ```

With `BTFollow` as the original value, the value is `BTFollow1` after the first iteration, and in the second iteration you then append `2` to *that*, resulting in `BTFollow12`, and so on.

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288790/45375) works (though `-like` should be replaced with `-eq`) and, given its appealing concision and the presumed relative rarity of duplicate names, is probably the way to go.

The following solution provides optimizations, but the required complexity may not be worth it; at least I hope it showcases some interesting techniques.

---

You can **avoid a costly loop around `Get-AdUser` altogether**, by pre-filtering potential duplicates with `Get-ADUser -Filter` and then processing the candidates locally:

```
$highestIndexSoFar =
  Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$UserName*'" | 
    ForEach-Object { if ($_.SamAccountName -match '\d*$') { [int] $Matches[0] } } |
      Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

if ($null -eq $highestIndexSoFar) { # no duplicates -> use as-is
    $UniqueUserName = $UserName
} else { # increment the highest index to date to make the username unique
    $UniqueUserName = $UserName + (1 + $highestIndexSoFar)
}
```

Another advantage of the above solution is that it determines the highest number suffix in the actual names, which **reliably uses a suffix that is the *highest to date* + 1**, whereas the call-`Get-AdUser`-in-a-loop approach uses the first index that *isn't taken* (though that would only be a concern if users got deleted over time or if out-of-sequence suffixes were manually created).

- `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$UserName*'"` retrieves *potential* duplicates; the `-Filter` syntax isn't sophisticated enough to allow regex-based matching, so this pre-filtering can only find all usernames that share the same prefix, which may include false positives (e.g., `jdoet` for `jdoe`, whereas ultimately only a *numeric* suffix such as `jdoe1` should be considered).
- Regex `'\d*$'` is then used to weed out such false positives, and the actual, potentially empty numeric suffix (`\d*`) is reflected in the automatic `$Matches` variable's `[0]` entry.
- The numeric suffix, if present or empty, is then cast to `[int]` and output.

  - Note that an initially unindexed username such as `BTFollow` will cause `$Matches[0]` to be the empty string, which cast `[int]` converts to `0`, so the first index appended will be `1`.
- `Sort-Object -Descending` sorts the resulting numbers in descending order, and `Select-Object -First 1` then extracts the first - i.e. the highest - suffix number found, if any.
- If no matches are found at all, i.e. if the username isn't taken yet, there is nothing to sort, and `Select-Object -First 1` effectively yields `$null`; otherwise, `1` must be added to highest number to form the new unique username.

**Caveat**: This approach may still fail if others are creating users *simultaneously*.

Comment: Your filtered solution works great. One question I can't figure out. Assuming you are using a new unique name (no existing match in AD), when you assign the top of the array to `$highestIndexSoFar` you get an error about indexing a null array. Which is what you would expect and the results are correct. But I HATE error messages. I was trying to use `-errorAction SilentlyContinue` to get around it, but that doesn't work in that case. Any ideas?

Comment: Good point about indexing into the null array, @Dave. Please see my update, which uses `Select-Object -First 1` to avoid the problem, and also simplifies the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out with the help of Reddit. I needed to replace my current code.

```
Do {
    Try {
        Get-ADUser $UserName | Out-Null
        $UserName = $Username + ++$i
        Continue
    }
    Catch {
        Break
    }
} While ($True)
```

New code that works.

```
#Check username does not exist, if it does add numbers
$UniqueUserName = $Username 
while (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$UniqueUserName'"){
  $UniqueUserName = $Username + ++$i
}
```